# UI-Router index.html page and different home page for specific state

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make something where when you go to the home page, it will show a clean one page site that describes what the product is.  Once you login, in the same app, I want to use a completely different style.  Different nav-bar, different CSS, basically a completely new page.  Right now I have the nav-bar inside of index.html, and then have the content injected into a container further down.  How would I completely use a different file for a certain state?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show up some code ?

Comment: use different `templateUrl` in your states

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this..

One is in Backend you can decide in backend which template to be sent to front end for display.

second is in frontend using some javascript framework which will decide what contents should be shown.

if both of ur pages are small go with frontend. if both pages are heavy go with backend. And if there is lot of logic to it.. use different url for  for two different pages.